# Group objects in the hierarchy

Tags: unity, parent, groups

I want to group 3 objects in the hierarchy, so its sorted in unity's hierarchy, but when I CTRL+P the objects, the active object becomes an non individual object in unity and I cant select it in unity.

What a want: Group: 1, 2, 3.

What I get: Group: 2, 3.

Its really hard to explain this, at least for me, but maybe someone understands? I'll post pics of what i mean if needed.

Comment: Parent them all to an empty object.

Comment: Huh, kinda redundant, but it works. TY.